# Textmate 2: How can increase font size of sections in the markup code?

Tags: textmate

Now that TextMate 2 has gone open-source, I have a reason to move from TeXShop to TextMate 2.

There is a great feature in the markdown bundle (`markdown.tmbundle`), which makes the headings in code look like:

[image: Textmate 2: Markdown Header]

The very same thing in using the latex bundle (`latex.tmbundle`) results in:

[image: Textmate 2: Latex Header (Section)]

**Question**: How can I implement the larger text size (perhaps even colors) in code for sections/subsections/subsubsections in the latex bundle?

The original question was posted on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834470/textmate-2-scope-increase-font-size-for-section-in-latex-document), where I have even put a bounty on it to no avail. Perhaps the community here will be more helpful.

Comment: Did you ask the question here: https://github.com/textmate/textmate/issues

Comment: No, because this is not an issue with the program that needs fixing. It is merely an extension of the latex bundle, which already exists. Thanks for tip though.

Comment: Update: I asked the question there and it was denied for the reason I expected. It is not a problem with the program.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am interested in a solution, too.

Comment: It makes sense why it would be rejected from the main textmate github issues section, but why they didn't refer you to: https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/issues is beyond me. I can open up an issue over there if you wish.

Comment: It is a question I would ask in the textmate mailing list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The procedure to change the appearance of section in Texmate 2 is the following:

In the `Bundle editor` menu, select `Edit bundles ...`.

Then select the bundle `Themes`.

From menu `File`, select `New`, and when prompted select `Setting`

Give a name to the setting.

In the Scope Selector field use `meta.function.section.latex`

Then you can edit the setting, for example:

```
{   
    fontName = 'Courier';
    fontSize = 36;
}
```

Then save (in the usual way, e.g, `command-s`).

You can repeat for other sectioning command (to identify the scope, move the cursor on the appropriate place and then use the following key combination `control-shift-P`)

---

**Update**: There was a feature request to give the different kinds of section tags unique tags so that be given different sizes. The scopes are now:

- meta.function.section.section.latex
- meta.function.section.subsection.latex
- meta.function.section.subsubsection.latex
- meta.function.section.chapter.latex
- meta.function.section.part.latex
- meta.function.section.addpart.latex
- meta.function.section.addchap.latex
- meta.function.section.addsec.latex
- meta.function.section.minisec.latex

You can create multiple setting items to target different items, if you want multiple scopes to share the same size you can separate the scopes with a comma in the scope field.

The user that requested this feature has [created a bundle](https://github.com/bcomnes/LaTeX-Section-Font-Sizes.tmbundle) that does this.

[image]

Comment: Absolutely wonderful! I would not have figured that out as I was looking in the Latex bundle and trying to customize it that way. All attempts have failed. I assume this same functionality can be mimicked in Sublime Text 2.

Comment: I'm not sure that the function is available in Sublime Text 2. It may be worth to request such a feature.

Comment: pushing control-shift-p in sublime text 2 reveals the scope as meta.function.section.latex (same). I just need to apply formatting to it properly.

Comment: Just to followup, Greg from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136024/sublime-text-2-build-system-custom-selector/14263821#comment21250027_14263821 says it is not possible with Sublime Text 2, because there is no setting for fontSize, just the ability to set bold, italic, or background color (and perhaps others, excluding size). It looks like I will stick with Textmate 2!

Comment: I just noticed these extra scopes and will update the [bundle](https://github.com/bcomnes/LaTeX-Font-Settings.tmbundle) accordingly.

Comment: I tried this but now the line doesn't wrap in those titles, why is that?